# What does ViewRootlmpl.mAttachInfo means?

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, leakcanary

[image]

Hello, I am getting strange memory leak on my app. How should I solve it and what can cause it? This leaks occurs before I want to create Fragment

```
**Called onCreate**
private void initRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.documentsRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

        TestRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new TestRecyclerViewAdapter(
              Test.getValues(), this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

  @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (recyclerView != null) {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(null);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(null);
        recyclerView = null;
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
**I add fragment observing LiveData and set layout Container as root Activity layout**
private void addTestFragment() {
    TestFragment test = new TestFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_activity_layout, test, TEST_FRAGMENT)
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: An image of the cause without the code is just as useless as the code without the error.

Comment: @TheWanderer I can't share code here, but basically it should be alright. I follow all required principles.

Comment: If you can't share code we can't answer your question. We're not mind readers.

Comment: @TheWanderer ok I have updated